# Disabling "New Tag collected" message on android

Tags: android, react-native, nfc

As a normal behaviour, Android shows up a "New Tag collected" message when it reads an NFC tag.
However, I do not want this message to appear when I use my app.
I searched for many solutions on the internet, but with no success.
Any ideas about what I can do?
I will share the function I use to get the tag's ID and my AndroidManifest.xml.

```
const readNFC = async (): Promise<string | undefined> => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.NdefFormatable);
      const tag = await NfcManager.getTag();
      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        await NfcManager.setAlertMessageIOS('TAG detect');
      }
      NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
      if (tag) {
        resolve(tag.id);
      }
    } catch (er) {
      reject('An error has occurred.');
    }
  });
};
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.newronda">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.hello.sample.nfcmanager" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```